# Yes and No functionality which starts with a blank state

Tags: dynamic-ui

I have options which require a user to start with a blank state, and then either choose Yes, or No. Is this pattern available anywhere? This is what I figured. Please let me know if this is valid. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, Dennis, and KK. Appreciate your help. I do want to go the conventional way, and not reinvent this pattern. I found the neutral radio button being used, and something similar to the pattern I have shown above.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple radio button is the natural choice for an interaction where there are two options, with no default. Hiding the options in some sort of dropdown as suggested, adds unnecessary clicks and thinking to the process.